# Optimizing text length of limited space

Tags: javascript, string, html, width, space

I am displaying text strings of varying characters and length in a div of fixed width. I'd like to fit as much text as possible in the allotted space. My current approach is to limit the number of text characters in the following way

```
var n = //some number
string = string.substr(0,n);
```

The problem with this approach is that different characters have different widths so while it can cap over spill it often leaves unused space. I've tried giving the containing div the following css properties.

```
div{
   width:200px
   white-space:nowrap
}
```

But the text still wraps to the next line down once it over spills the width. Can someone help me out with a good practice way of addressing this problem.

Comment: Please provide [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net) that shows the problem at hand

Answer (score 1):

You might try [text-overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow)

From [quirks mode](http://quirksmode.org/css/user-interface/textoverflow.html):

> text-overflow comes into play only when:
>
> the box has overflow other than visible (with overflow: visible the text simply flows out of the box)
>   the box has white-space: nowrap or a similar method of constraining the way the text is laid out. (Without this, the text would wrap to the next line)

Style change:

```
div{
   width:200px;
   white-space:nowrap;
   overflow: hidden;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AXMLv/)

Comment: Thanks for your response, your css does prevent wrapping but it doesn't seem to provide any width limiting.

Comment: Perhaps something else is getting in the way.  With a bare html doc and only a single div, this works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the actual width of the text using a method such as the one described here: https://coderwall.com/p/kdi8ua.

Then keep adding characters until the width is larger than the width of your element, and remove 1.

Here is the function from the site linked to:

```
// Calculate width of text from DOM element or string. By Phil Freo <http://philfreo.com>
$.fn.textWidth = function(text, font) {
    if (!$.fn.textWidth.fakeEl) $.fn.textWidth.fakeEl = $('<span>').hide().appendTo(document.body);
    $.fn.textWidth.fakeEl.html(text || this.val() || this.text()).css('font', font || this.css('font'));
    return $.fn.textWidth.fakeEl.width();
};
```